# How to add a parameter to the class?

Tags: php, class, post

On page test.php i send form with method post.

**Сode page test.php**

```
var_dump($_POST);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
```

When i use `var_dump($_POST)`, i can see

```
array(1) {
  ["prod"]=>
  string(7) "4477535"
}
```

**Part сode page UploadHandler.php**

```
class UploadHandler
{
......
function add_img($img)
    {
    $prod=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST('prod'));
    $add_to_db = $this->query("INSERT INTO prods (`prod`, `image`, `main`) VALUES ('$prod','".$img."','')") or die(mysql_error());
    return $add_to_db;
    }
...
}
```

When i use this code i have **500 Internal Server Error**

**With firebug i see POST**

```
-----------------------------20037128598723 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="prod"

4477535

-----------------------------20037128598723
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]";
filename="Penguins.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpeg
...
...
...
-----------------------------20037128598723--
```

Tell me please how add **$_POST('prod')** to class?

Comment: `500 Internal Server Error` doesn't sufficiently describe what error occurred or where it occurred. As far as passing `$_POST('prod')` as a parameter is concerned, it is a superglobal. It should be accessible everywhere.

Comment: `$_POST` is not a function.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error in the php

```
 $prod=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST('prod'));
```

use this instead

```
  $prod=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prod']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$_POST('prod')`, use `$_POST['prod']`.

If that doesn't solve the whole problem, you need to add more details as to what the specific error message is.  A 500 Internal Server Error only means that PHP outputted some stuff on STDERR.  Check your logs.

Comment: no need. this good help. I relaxed and write () instead [].